# 50/60 Hz signals and ADC sampling frequency

Tags: frequency, sampling, rms

As some of my previous posts, I'm trying to find the RMS of sine wave during the first cycle, but I still have some questions as for the sampling frequency.

Let's say I choose a sampling frequency of 1 kHz. That's one sample per millisecond.
For a 50 Hz signal: 20 ms/1 ms = 20 samples per cycle.
For a 60 Hz signal: 16.67 ms/ 1 ms = 17 samples per cycle

But my system won't know if it's a 50 Hz or 60 Hz signal to adjust the number of samples, so is there a way to capture both frequencies with a common number of samples and sampling frequency? My application is to measure only earth leakage current. No intention to find power.

Comment: There will be 2 zero crossings in any cycle. Measure the time between them and even with 1 ms sampling you can discriminate between 50 and 60Hz before the end of the cycle.

Answer (score 4):

> But my system won't know if it's a 50 Hz or 60 Hz signal to adjust the number of samples, so is there a way to capture both frequencies with a common number of samples and sampling frequency?

Start measuring at a zero crossing, and then measure until you see two more zero crossings.  This will ensure that you always have one full cycle of the waveform, even if you do not know the frequency in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this isn't too slow: take 100 samples (0.1 second). This will give you 5 full cycles of a 50Hz signal, or 6 full cycles of 60Hz; either way, it's a whole number so you will be able to compute an accurate RMS, and it should be a bit less noisy than just capturing a single cycle anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To capture just one full cycle of both frequencies with one sampling rate and buffer size is impossible, as the periods are different. Typically one would oversample in situations like that. Also, to consider effects of the noise in captured data, multiple cycles of the signal will help make the result more accurate.

What is possible, is to calculate a higher sampling frequency Fsampl and size of the buffer Nsampl, so it captures whole cycles of target frequencies no matter which of the 50Hz or 60Hz is present, and can then use one calculation without worrying about signal cycle boundaries.

Fsampl = LCM(F1, F2)

where LCM() is a least common multiple function, can be calculated by the following formula:

LCM(a,b)=a*b/GCM(a,b)

where GCM() is a greatest common divisor function, can be calculated by the following sequence (Euclidean Algorithm):

1. If a = 0 then GCD(a,b)=b, since the GCD(0,b)=b, and we can stop.
2. If a = 0 then GCD(a,b)=a, since the GCD(a,0)=a, and we can stop.
3. Write a in quotient remainder form (a = b⋅Q + r)
4. Find GCD(b,r) using the Euclidean Algorithm (recursively) since GCD(a,b) = GCD(b,r)

Using the given method, for given 50Hz and 60Hz, LCM(50Hz,60Hz)=300 Hz.

Now, to determine the size of the buffer (and sampling duration), we can use the following formula:

Nsampl = LCM(Fsampl/F1, Fsampl/F2)

It will give 30 samples at 300Hz for 100ms duration, and will capture 5 cycles of 50Hz and 6 cycles of 60Hz.

Note: Fsampl should be checked against Nyquist (sampling) theorem, and multiplied by 2 if it is not more than 2x of either frequencies. For 50Hz and 60Hz it is not a problem, but if there was e.g. 10Hz and 20Hz signal plugged into the equation, the formulae would lead to bad design with 20Hz disappearing from the samples (aliased to 0Hz). So the complete formula is:

Fsampl = LCM(F1, F2) * (1 if LCM(F1,2)>2*max(F1,F2) else 2)

Comment: Assuming it is a symmetrical sine wave, you only need an integral number of half-cycles, so a sampling period of 50 ms will work for 50 or 60 Hz